# Parse JSON to dictionary, issue with true and false

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary, afnetworking

I have a JSON that return me one of key:

"fork": false or "fork": true

when I look into the dictionary there is a

fork = 0; or fork = 1;

but when I try to invoke this code

```
BOOL forkExist;

    if (dictionary[@"fork"])
    {
        if ((BOOL)dictionary[@"fork"])
        {
            NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> EXIST %@", dictionary[@"fork"]);
            forkExist = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> NOT EXIST %@", dictionary[@"fork"]);
            forkExist = NO;
        }
    }
```

it very time run for me NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> EXIST %@", dictionary[@"fork"]); and never second NSLog

This is a log

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> EXIST 0
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> EXIST 1
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> EXIST 0
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> EXIST 0
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> EXIST 0
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> EXIST 1
```

But as you can see it never call NOT EXIST even in case that there are 0 values.

I have checked class of dictionary[@"fork"] and it say that it is an `__NSCFBoolean` but when app compare it seems it does not work

Comment: dictionary[@"fork"] is pointer with value is address of memory and !=0. (BOOL) will convert this address to true and never be zero if this pointer!= nil

Answer (score 3):

The dictionary will contain an NSNumber @0 or @1 for the `BOOL`, and the object handle is always "truthy", so...

```
BOOL forkExist = [dictionary[@"fork"] boolValue];
```

should work properly.